# How can I get ride of a flicker in my skrollr animation in firefox and IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, animation, flicker, skrollr

I have a one page animation using skrollr. The animation looks fine in Safari and Chrome but flickers in IE and FF. In firefox when scrolling back up and down through the animation the flickering goes away and the animation is smooth, IE flickers no matter what. The animation has transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
and backface-visibility: hidden; to force hardware acceleration and all images are preloaded. Here is a link to the animation: http://total-equipment.com/products/coiled-tubing-unit/ and this is the code structure:

HTML

```
<div class="container" id="arena"> 
            <div id="animate"
            data-anchor-target="#arena" 
>
                  <img class="lazy" data-anchor-target="#arena" src="img/animations/ctu_hq_animation_mb_4.0001.png" alt="" data-0-top="display:none;" data--100-top="display:block;" data--125-top="display:none;">
                  <img class="lazy" data-anchor-target="#arena" src="img/animations/ctu_hq_animation_mb_4.0003.png" alt="" data-0-top="display:none;" data--125-top="display:block;" data--150-top="display:none;">
                  <img class="lazy" data-anchor-target="#arena" src="img/animations/ctu_hq_animation_mb_4.0004.png" alt="" data-0-top="display:none;" data--150-top="display:block;" data--175-top="display:none;">
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
img {
    height: 500px;
    width: 800px;

}

#arena {
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 900px;
    background-size: 900px 800px;
}
#animate {
    width: 850px;
    height: 650px;
    position: fixed;
    background-size: 900px 800px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    left: 10%;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few lines in firebug that are giving errors.  For example, line 438 looks like this:

```
<img class="anim-image"data-anchor-target="#arena"  
src="http://total-equipment.com/wp-content/themes/teas/img/animations/ctu_hq_animation_mb_4.0010.png" alt="" 
data-0-top="display:none;" 
data--450-top="display:block;"  
data--500-top="display:none;">
```

Whereas all the other lines around it look like:

```
<img class="anim-image" data-smooth-scrolling="off" data-anchor-target="#arena" 
src="" data-src="http://total-equipment.com/wp-content/themes/teas/img/animations/ctu_hq_animation_mb_4.0009.png" alt="" 
data-0-top="display:none;" 
data--400-top="display:block;" 
data--450-top="display:none;">
```

One has `data-src` and the other line with the error just has `src`.

Comment: Yes sorry I should have noted that, I have tried both the global and element. The site is modeled after the animation on moto.oakley.com which also has a slight flicker in firefox on the first run through.

Comment: Ok, I did notice in firebug that there are a couple of lines showing errors.  I updated my answer to give you an idea.

Comment: Thank you I'll look into the errors. But I recently added those data-src attr. It still flickered before they were added. I added them to prevent all the animation images from downloading onmobile. There's a function in the header that says if screen size is desktop change data-src to src else do nothing wich prevents them all being downloaded.